Lebesgue measure of the boundary of attracting basin
Topological dynamics is not my area of expertise, but when investigating the essential spectra of the operators of the form
$(Tf)(z) = w(z)f(B(z))$ acting on the disc-algebra, where $B$ is a finite Blaschke product (not a Moebius transformation), I became interested in the following question: are there examples of finite Blaschke products such that the Julia set has  Lebesgue measure zero?
I would be also interested in a weaker form of the question: is there a hyperbolic Blaschke product such that the Lebesgue measure of the boundary of the attracting basin is zero?

The Julia set is either the unit circle or a Cantor subset of the unit circle
